# Template source location media folder

Tags: media-library, datasource

When I create a template entry for an image with source location like

```
/sitecore/media library/Icons/Bezahlarten
```

[image]

I've added some images to this folder, but when I whant to select an image for this I see only this:

[image]

and I thought I would directly see all images inside this folder.

Only when I enable the treeview on the right and manually open the "Bezahlarten" folder I can select an image.

[image]

What can I do that I see the images directly when opening the media selection dialog?

simple search I can fin the picture
[image]

Comment: Can you find those items in Content Editor with a simple search? Also, just guessing here, but do those media items have versions in en language?

Comment: @SteveMcGill I've added a simple search result above and I can find the image. My default language is German, they have no version  in EN currently

Comment: So you shouldn't have to, but just suspecting a potential bug, can you see if the problem is "solved" if you add a EN version?

Comment: It will came up if you add the EN version as the timestamp of the Updated field will change. I think you'll need to contact sitecore support about this. I did a test on a local instance and i have an image in the EN version but it does not display on the media dialog. Once i added or update a field on the media item, it appears on the dialog.

Comment: after adding the EN Version it shows up now seems to be a bug and not a problem with the source path I am using.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding `sitecore_master_index`?

Comment: good hint I will try it next time, currently it is working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Sitecore 8.2 update 7.

Sitecore has registered this as a bug with reference number **#95466**

They provided me with a patch, the patch has the following description:

> This patch ignores the language parameter during the search on Select
>   Media Dialog.

If you ask Sitecore Support they will send you a link to the patch.